# Why Apple decided to deprecate majority of methods of UIAlertView in iOS 9.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

While poking around Apple's Documentation I have witnessed that they have deprecated majority of methods in UIAlertView class. Are there any alternatives for that?

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIAlertViewStyle

Answer (score 4):

Nobody outside of the core iOS team knows exactly why Apple does anything, but my guess is that they are trying to shove (or gently encourage) developers into using the newer ([and more flexible](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/)) [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIAlertController/alertControllerWithTitle:message:preferredStyle:), which came in with iOS 8.0.